# Postgres select query with exclusice lock performance issue

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance, rds

Recently while fixing a production bug I used PostgreSQL exclusive lock and learned a lesson the hard way. Just a simple lock drastically impacted the performance of the server and I had to revert the code while leaving the bug again in the system. I was certain that it would impact the performance but had no idea of its severity.

A query exclusive lock on 10000 rows took **70** millis. While the same query without the lock took just **10** millis.

[image]

[image]

I still need to fix this issue and have no idea of a better mechanism to do so. Is there a way to improve the performance of such queries. Or do I need to look for an alternative solution?

I did find a few articles about the performance impact of locks on queries but nothing really good!

**Edit 1:**

Maybe it was too quick to come to that conclusion that locks were the problem.

```
explain (analyze,buffers, timing) select * from job where id in (1642390498,1642392044,1642393079,1642391026,1642393074,1642391037,1642390526,1642390527,1642391544,1642392056,1642392568,1642390520,1642393081,1642391035,1642390468,1642392005,1642392006,1642390470,1642389959,1642390471,1641402865,1642390466,1642390476,1642392525,1642393039,1642389960,1642391511,1642392528,1642393040,1642390993,1642391507,1642393052,1642390492,1642393048,1642390488,1642390491,1642389927,1642390947,1642392483,1642391976,1642390953,1641401243,1642389940,1642391478,1642389943,1642389938,1642393021,1642390971,1642391428,1642390918,1642389888,1642390925,1642392458,1642391440,1642390416,1642390931,1642391443,1642390428,1642391966,1642392472,1642390937,1642392474,1642392475,1642390372,1642391397,1642391392,1642391906,1642392428,1642387311,1642390383,1642391403,1642391924,1642389878,1642392433,1642390385,1642390393,1642390394,1642390860,1642391886,1642387273,1642387274,1642393419,1642392404,1642390878,1642391390,1642393383,1642391330,1642392874,1642391857,1642527493,1642390785,1642390283,1642391318,1642391319,1642390800,1642390290,1642391326,1642392346,1642390811,1642390299,1642392293,1642536677,1642390752,1642391265,1642391276,1642391788,1642391789,1642390253,1642391279,1642392296,1642390763,1642391284,1642391283,1642393331,1642391288,1642392313,1642390265,1642391238,1642393286,1642391239,1642390208,1642391234,1642392268,1642392270,1642391759,1642391240,1642391241,1642391242,1642391243,1642390231,1642390226,1642392796,1642390237,1642391771,1642390235,1642390692,1642390180,1642390688,1642390689,1642391713,1642390177,1642390690,1642393250,1642393260,1642391726,1642392239,1642391208,1642390185,1642392244,1642391221,1642393270,1642392752,1642392753,1642391218,1642392754,1642390194,1642391219,1642391229,1642390712,1642391225,1642392250,1642390715,1642393275,1642390662,1642391175,1642538627,1642392707,1642538624,1642391178,1642391690,1642392715,1642390155,1642390678,1642392209,1642390161,1642393235,1642392220,1642390684,1642390686,1642391654,1642392166,1642392160,1642390632,1642538602,1642390633,1642391158,1642391153,1641402944,1642391676,1642393213,1642391166,1642392696,1642393208,1642393209,1642390650,1642392187,1642391620,1642537031,1642390085,1642390086,1642392640,1642391105,1642390605,1642391113,1642390613,1642390102,1642393175,1642390615,1642391132,1642392670,1642392664,1642392097,1642393121,1642391084,1642390060,1642392621,1642393130,1642390570,1642390068,1642393142,1642393143,1642390064,1642392113,1642392627,1642390579,1642390589,1642392126,1642390079,1642390073,1642393147,1642392583,1642390528,1642391042,1641402931,1642391566,1642387466,1642393099,1641401914,1642387467,1642390037,1642393111,1642387475,1642390559,1642391579) for update;




 LockRows  (cost=0.00..3757.09 rows=1347 width=250) (actual time=0.358..1.554 rows=505 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3227
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3743.62 rows=1347 width=250) (actual time=0.350..1.301 rows=505 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=2717
         ->  Seq Scan on job  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=1622) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = ANY ('{1642390498,1642392044,1642393079,1642391026,1642393074,1642391037,1642390526,1642390527,1642391544,1642392056,1642392568,1642390520,1642393081,1642391035,1642390468,1642392005,1642392006,1642390470,1642389959,1642390471,1641402865,1642390466,1642390476,1642392525,1642393039,1642389960,1642391511,1642392528,1642393040,1642390993,1642391507,1642393052,1642390492,1642393048,1642390488,1642390491,1642389927,1642390947,1642392483,1642391976,1642390953,1641401243,1642389940,1642391478,1642389943,1642389938,1642393021,1642390971,1642391428,1642390918,1642389888,1642390925,1642392458,1642391440,1642390416,1642390931,1642391443,1642390428,1642391966,1642392472,1642390937,1642392474,1642392475,1642390372,1642391397,1642391392,1642391906,1642392428,1642387311,1642390383,1642391403,1642391924,1642389878,1642392433,1642390385,1642390393,1642390394,1642390860,1642391886,1642387273,1642387274,1642393419,1642392404,1642390878,1642391390,1642393383,1642391330,1642392874,1642391857,1642527493,1642390785,1642390283,1642391318,1642391319,1642390800,1642390290,1642391326,1642392346,1642390811,1642390299,1642392293,1642536677,1642390752,1642391265,1642391276,1642391788,1642391789,1642390253,1642391279,1642392296,1642390763,1642391284,1642391283,1642393331,1642391288,1642392313,1642390265,1642391238,1642393286,1642391239,1642390208,1642391234,1642392268,1642392270,1642391759,1642391240,1642391241,1642391242,1642391243,1642390231,1642390226,1642392796,1642390237,1642391771,1642390235,1642390692,1642390180,1642390688,1642390689,1642391713,1642390177,1642390690,1642393250,1642393260,1642391726,1642392239,1642391208,1642390185,1642392244,1642391221,1642393270,1642392752,1642392753,1642391218,1642392754,1642390194,1642391219,1642391229,1642390712,1642391225,1642392250,1642390715,1642393275,1642390662,1642391175,1642538627,1642392707,1642538624,1642391178,1642391690,1642392715,1642390155,1642390678,1642392209,1642390161,1642393235,1642392220,1642390684,1642390686,1642391654,1642392166,1642392160,1642390632,1642538602,1642390633,1642391158,1642391153,1641402944,1642391676,1642393213,1642391166,1642392696,1642393208,1642393209,1642390650,1642392187,1642391620,1642537031,1642390085,1642390086,1642392640,1642391105,1642390605,1642391113,1642390613,1642390102,1642393175,1642390615,1642391132,1642392670,1642392664,1642392097,1642393121,1642391084,1642390060,1642392621,1642393130,1642390570,1642390068,1642393142,1642393143,1642390064,1642392113,1642392627,1642390579,1642390589,1642392126,1642390079,1642390073,1642393147,1642392583,1642390528,1642391042,1641402931,1642391566,1642387466,1642393099,1641401914,1642387467,1642390037,1642393111,1642387475,1642390559,1642391579}'::bigint[]))
               ...
               ...
               ...
               ...
              Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1642390498,1642392044,1642393079,1642391026,1642393074,1642391037,1642390526,1642390527,1642391544,1642392056,1642392568,1642390520,1642393081,1642391035,1642390468,1642392005,1642392006,1642390470,1642389959,1642390471,1641402865,1642390466,1642390476,1642392525,1642393039,1642389960,1642391511,1642392528,1642393040,1642390993,1642391507,1642393052,1642390492,1642393048,1642390488,1642390491,1642389927,1642390947,1642392483,1642391976,1642390953,1641401243,1642389940,1642391478,1642389943,1642389938,1642393021,1642390971,1642391428,1642390918,1642389888,1642390925,1642392458,1642391440,1642390416,1642390931,1642391443,1642390428,1642391966,1642392472,1642390937,1642392474,1642392475,1642390372,1642391397,1642391392,1642391906,1642392428,1642387311,1642390383,1642391403,1642391924,1642389878,1642392433,1642390385,1642390393,1642390394,1642390860,1642391886,1642387273,1642387274,1642393419,1642392404,1642390878,1642391390,1642393383,1642391330,1642392874,1642391857,1642527493,1642390785,1642390283,1642391318,1642391319,1642390800,1642390290,1642391326,1642392346,1642390811,1642390299,1642392293,1642536677,1642390752,1642391265,1642391276,1642391788,1642391789,1642390253,1642391279,1642392296,1642390763,1642391284,1642391283,1642393331,1642391288,1642392313,1642390265,1642391238,1642393286,1642391239,1642390208,1642391234,1642392268,1642392270,1642391759,1642391240,1642391241,1642391242,1642391243,1642390231,1642390226,1642392796,1642390237,1642391771,1642390235,1642390692,1642390180,1642390688,1642390689,1642391713,1642390177,1642390690,1642393250,1642393260,1642391726,1642392239,1642391208,1642390185,1642392244,1642391221,1642393270,1642392752,1642392753,1642391218,1642392754,1642390194,1642391219,1642391229,1642390712,1642391225,1642392250,1642390715,1642393275,1642390662,1642391175,1642538627,1642392707,1642538624,1642391178,1642391690,1642392715,1642390155,1642390678,1642392209,1642390161,1642393235,1642392220,1642390684,1642390686,1642391654,1642392166,1642392160,1642390632,1642538602,1642390633,1642391158,1642391153,1641402944,1642391676,1642393213,1642391166,1642392696,1642393208,1642393209,1642390650,1642392187,1642391620,1642537031,1642390085,1642390086,1642392640,1642391105,1642390605,1642391113,1642390613,1642390102,1642393175,1642390615,1642391132,1642392670,1642392664,1642392097,1642393121,1642391084,1642390060,1642392621,1642393130,1642390570,1642390068,1642393142,1642393143,1642390064,1642392113,1642392627,1642390579,1642390589,1642392126,1642390079,1642390073,1642393147,1642392583,1642390528,1642391042,1641402931,1642391566,1642387466,1642393099,1641401914,1642387467,1642390037,1642393111,1642387475,1642390559,1642391579}'::bigint[]))

               Buffers: shared hit=1253

 Planning time: 2.177 ms

 Execution time: 1.778 ms
```

After analyzing the RDS logs, it seems that the actual problem is queries waiting too long to acquire the lock.

Another type of queries logged in error logs was:

```
FAREYE@TRIP_SERVICE_PROD:
[8983]:LOG:
DURATION:
990.926 MS  EXECUTE
S_38:
UPDATE
    JOB_5_2020
SET
    ID                      =   $1
,   LATITUDE                =   $2
,   LONGITUDE               =   $3
WHERE
    UNIQUE_ID   =   $32
```

Now that I think about it, the 990 ms is mostly waiting for the lock rather than actually executing the query. How do I identify if it was waiting for the lock-in RDS Error logs? can I activate such logging in any way?

Comment: Please don't post text as images.  And certainly not as images which have had the important bits thrown away.

Comment: You can try to use `log_lock_wait` parameter to log waiting locks but this can be expensive because it is using `deadlock_timeout` parameter and I am not sure it's the right thing to do if you lock thousands of rows in a single"SELECT for UPDATE" statement. Another possibility is to use extensions that are sampling wait events like pg_wait_sampling or pg_sentinel. I don't know if they can be used with RDS or if RDS has other features.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL implements row locking by writing some information into the row headers so  this takes time. [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) says:

> PostgreSQL doesn't remember any information about modified rows in
>   memory, so there is no limit on the number of rows locked at one time.
>   However, locking a row might cause a disk write, e.g., SELECT FOR
>   UPDATE modifies selected rows to mark them locked, and so will result
>   in disk writes.

On a simple table with 10000 rows I have without for UPDATE clause:

```
postgres=# explain (analyze,buffers, timing) select * from t ;
                                             QUERY PLAN                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..198.00 rows=10000 width=8) (actual time=0.060..1.207 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=98
 Planning Time: 0.046 ms
 Execution Time: 1.860 ms
(4 rows)
```

with FOR UPDATE clause:

```
postgres=# explain (analyze,buffers, timing) select * from t  for update;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LockRows  (cost=0.00..298.00 rows=10000 width=14) (actual time=0.066..9.158 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=20098
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..198.00 rows=10000 width=14) (actual time=0.045..1.474 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=98
 Planning Time: 0.039 ms
 Execution Time: 9.807 ms
(6 rows)
```

In my case it's about 5 times slower with FOR UPDATE clause.

Maybe it takes more time because it seems you have partitions: maybe you have more data to read.

Did you run VACUUM or ANALYZE recently on these tables ?

Try to give code output as text instead of images: it is easier to read text than images.

Please post output of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,TIMING) for your queries with `track_io_timing=on` in your session.